# overruling property from parent bean

Tags: spring, annotations

I'm trying to convert an application from XML based to annotation based wiring. I'm looking for  a solutions for the following (simplified for this question):

```
Class A {
   @Autowired
   Object myProp;
}

Class B extends A {
   // has an Object myProp from it's parent 
}
```

In XML there was a bean A, and a bean B with parent A. B is exactly the same, but it has an overruled myProp:

```
<bean class="A" name="a">
    <property name="myProp" value-ref="someRef"/>
    ....
</bean>
<bean class="B" parent="a">
    <property name="myProp" value-ref="someOtherRef"/>
</bean>
```

How can I accomplish this with annotations? There is no code in B where I can specify which bean I want injected into myProp.

Comment: define a common factory method without `@Bean` call that from both `@Bean` methods and override/change what is needed. Also inheritance in beans doen'st mean  the classes have to extend each other! Bean definition inheritance isn't inheritance in thje java sense!.

Comment: where ... is in the XML, there are other settings that are also relevant for B, that's why they are wired this way. Also, the beans are used in apache camel routes, so there is no easy place to use a Factory (or: the code that uses the beans is not ours).

Comment: Why is it hard to create an `@Configuration` class with a `createBean` method which you call from 2 places. You can create an xml config so you can create an `@Configuration` class.

Comment: ok so the answer is: use a @Configuration class, to define beans outside of their own class files and without XML. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
class Config {
  @Bean
  public A a(SomeClass someClass) {
    A a = new A();
    a.myProp = someClass;
    return a;
  }

  @Bean
  public B b(SomeOtherClass someOtherClass) {
    B b = new B();
    b.myProp = someOtherClass;
    return b;
  }

  @Bean
  public SomeClass someClass() {
    return new SomeClass();
  }

  @Bean
  public SomeOtherClass someOtherClass() {
    return new SomeOtherClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you change the example to one where "new Object()" is replaced with references to different beans? the injected beans have e.g. different transaction isolation levels, so I really need a reference to an already configured bean instead of a new Object().

Comment: Done. Please review latest changes

Comment: ok, one more question: the beans I need are defined as a `@Component` in their own class files, so I would need to get a reference to those instead of creating them here. The `@Component` beans are also used elsewhere and they are autowired into the other beans without Configuration classes.

Comment: It doesn't matter how those beans are defined, they would be accessible in @Configuration class.
The only restriction is circular dependencies - spring must be able to define dependency tree for all beans.